Are random number sequences impacted by load state in NetLogo?
This is in relation to using middle knowledge with agent models (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2409.17196)
If I save a state using export-world in NetLogo and then load it repeatedly using import-world, will the random number sequences be identical each time after loading the state?
So if ask turtles is executed after the state is loaded, will the turtles be asked in exactly the same order every single time the same state is loaded? And for the entire rest of the run, no matter how long? And identical for every single ask command and anything else that generates random numbers? A quick test makes me think YES but does anyone know for sure? The user guide NetLogo Help says it saves "the state of the random number generator" so again I think it's YES.
So if NetLogo is about to use a random sequence 76549871123 and the state is saved after the 5 has been used, and then we exit NetLogo, open it again and load the saved state, will the next sequence be 49871123 and so on forever?


How do you "load the state" or what do you mean by this?
Does your "random sequence" represent all random numbers of a simulation or a specific one?


Sorry I'm talking about export-world/import-world. I'll edit the question now to specify.

After you refined the question I think you answered your question already correctly yourself. Yes, the random number sequences will be identical each time you import-world.

Seconded, the answer is yes.
